# Is the phrase ‘outgrow oneself’ correct?

Tags: grammar, variants

Is it correct to write like ‘**As soon as we outgrew ourself and became a capable individual, all the difficulties came roaring at us**’?

Comment: Needs more context.  But you have conflicting verb tenses between "outgrew" and "become".

Comment: My bad on the conflicting tenses, it’s supposed to be ‘became’. What I’m trying to ask is that whether the very selves of ours can be outgrown the way we outgrow our pants, belts and something like that. The expression of outgrowing oneself here is the same as the expression of growing up to be an adult.

Answer (score -1):

An idiom: **grow out of something** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/outgrow) and tr. v. **outgrew**

> Lit. to age out of something; to outgrow something; to abandon
>   something as one matures.   To lose or discard in the course of
>   maturation

As in:

> Finally, Ted grew out of his bedwetting. Haven't you grown out of your
>   fear of the dark yet?  She outgrew her youthful idealism.

Your sentence with a *suggested* edits:

> As soon as I outgrew my youth and became a capable individual, all
>   life's difficulties came roaring at me.

or

> As soon as we outgrow our youth and become capable individuals, all
>   of life's difficulties come roaring at us.